# Install node-mapnik on Windows

Tags: mapnik, windows, mapbox

After successfully working with node-mapnik (and the gorgeous vector tiles) on Linux I'm trying to set them up on Windows too, but have come to a dead end.

What I've done so far:

- Installed mapnik 2.2.0 SDK and added the bin and lib directories to the PATH.
- Using `npm install mapnik` shows an error about a missing cairo header file.
- Cloning the repository and adding the cairo directory to `binding.gyp` solved the header issue.
- Next error is about the target architecture (32 vs. 64bit), because the generated solution is 64bit only. I solved this by adjusting the gyp config parameters to get a Win32 target.
- Next errors are about missing boost libraries. I followed the tutorial on how to build mapnik dependencies on Windows to the letter and added the `boost-49-vc100\lib` directory to the `AdditionalLibraryDirectories`. Which results in this error:

  `Creating library C:\dev2\node-mapnik\node-mapnik\build\Release\_mapnik.lib
  and object C:\dev2\node-mapnik\node-mapnik\build\Release\_mapnik.exp
  LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs;
  use /NODEFAULTLIB:library [C:\dev2\node-mapnik\node-m apnik\build\_mapnik.vcxproj]
  mapnik_image_view.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl
  boost::throw_exception(class std::exception const & )" 
  (?throw_exception@boost@@YAXABVexception@std@@@Z) [C:\dev2\node-mapnik\
  node-mapnik\build\_mapnik.vcxproj]
  C:\dev2\node-mapnik\node-mapnik\build\Release\_mapnik.node : fatal error
  LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals [C:\dev2\node-mapnik\node- mapnik\
  build\_mapnik.vcxproj]`

Any suggestions on how to get node-mapnik (with vector tile support) running on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution (tested on W7-64 with node.js-32. 64bit currently not supported):

- use node-mapnik from Github
- get cairo sources: http://www.cairographics.org/
- copy `cairo-svg-surface.c`, `cairo-svg.h` and `cairo-svg-surface-private.h` to `C:\mapnik-v2.2.0\include`
- make proj4 epsg files available: `SET PROJ_LIB=C:\mapnik-v2.2.0\share\proj`
- now `npm install` should finish successfully, provided that all other requirements are met: mapnik SDK, Python, protobuf, etc, ...
- register all needed input plugins in your script (not auto registered in current Github source) e.g. shapefile input: `mapnik.register_datasource(path.join(mapnik.settings.paths.input_plugins,'shape.input'));`

Answer (score 1):

I've been following `mapnik` and `tilesplash`, and it is always a pain to get it installed on Windows. This is so far (as of Feb.16 2022) the most I could get:

- Tilesplash@3.1.3
- Node-Mapnik@3.6.2
- Node.js@8.17.0 64-bit
- Windows-build-tools for Microsoft VisualStudio 2017
- Windows 10 64-bit

How I got here:

1. Install [NVM for Windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows): (if you have other node.js packages that's not compatible with Node 8.X.X; If you don't, install Node.js 8.17.0 or whatever 8.X.X.)
2. Remove `C:\Users\<your username>\.windows-build-tools` if existed. Or not, if you don't want to mess up with your previous `windows-build-tools`. You probably have no such directory because you didn't try to install OS-dependent node modules.
3. Start command line as admin.
4. Do `nvm install 8.17.0`, then `nvm use 8.17.0`. (if you use nvm.)
5. Do `npm install --global --vs2017 --production windows-build-tools`. Wait until it says Python is installed, then make sure Visual Studio Installer is downloaded to `C:\Users\<your username>\.windows-build-tools` as `vs_BuildTools.exe`. The installation will appear stucked but don't worry. Ctrl-C to terminate this `npm install`.
6. Double click on `C:\Users\<your username>\.windows-build-tools\vs_BuildTools.exe` to manually install the required tools in VisualStudio 2017. Only `MSBuild Tools`, `Visual C++ build tools` and `Visual Studio Extensibility SDK` are required. It is sufficient to keep the default selections under these categories.
7. Do `npm config set msvs_version 2017`.
8. Do `set VCTargetsPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets`. I'm pretty sure this path exists if you properly installed VisualStudio 2017. Check if the path is properly set by `echo %VCTargetsPath%`.
9. Last but not least, `npm install mapnik@3.6.2`(and if you need to install `tilesplash`, do `npm install tilesplash` after mapnik is installed.)

Good luck! Currently I'm also watching the development of the mapnik build using `vcpkg`, but `vcpkg` itself is already something for me to study. This `vcpkg` build looks less OS-dependent and promising for higher `Node.js` versions.

So far I'm happy with my settings, but having to switch among Node.js versions is still a bit inconvenient so I'll keep watching.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is a linking issue: you likely need `/MD` while `/MT` is being set. See `Step 3` in my comment at https://github.com/mapnik/node-mapnik/issues/202#issuecomment-31876610.